# Modeled an MIP woth Pyomo in Python, cannot solve it with Gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi, pyomo

my goal in the end is to solve an MIP using Python.
I wanna formulate the model using Pyomo and solve it with Gurobi.

- Gurobi itself is working for smaller example MIPs that are **not** formulated with Pyomo.
- The pure formulation of a program with Pyomo also runs through **(without solving it)**.

When putting "everything together", I get:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doc'
```

I used the example from here: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Pyomo/PyomoGallery/blob/master/transport/transport.ipynb

I imported `gurobipy` and exchanged the solver "glpk" to "gurobi". And of course I added the environment that connects to the server of gurobi...

So my question is easy: How can I make it run?

I could not find any answers to that in the WWW. All tutorials used GLPK as example, but somehow it seems like I cannot really transfer it to the case with Gurobi as solver.

Thank you for every hint!

Comment: Does it work without `doc` or is that merely the first thing to go wrong?

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace for the error?  Also, which versions of Python, Pyomo and Gurobi are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To solve an optimisation problem using Pyomo and GUROBI as a solver, you need to first install the GUROBI in your system and activate the license using the following:

1. Install Gurobi: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/quickstart_windows/software_installation_guid.html
2. Activate the license: In your terminal type:

```html
grbgetkey <your license key>
```

Now when you solve the model, this should run automatically. On the other hand, GUROBIPY is a python library for solving optimisation problems like PYOMO. So in your case, you don't need GUROBIPY at any instance.